# Image in a div tag

Tags: css, image, html, background-image

What is the difference between them.The image appears only in the first case.Why doesnt in appear in the second case?

```
<div id='" + this.panelId + "Icon-1" + "'  style='width:34px;align:center;' class='iconDiv'><img id="+"Img"+ this.panelId+"  src="+"Images/i24_grey-info.png"+" /></div>



<div id='" + this.panelId + "Icon-1" + "'  style='width:34px;align:center; background-image:Images/i24_grey-info.png' class='iconDiv'></div>
```

Thanks to all . This works! But i get 4 images...i mean the image repeats 4 times :( why is that?

```
this.iconDiv = "<div id='" + this.panelId + "Icon-1" + "'  style='width:34px;height:34px; align:center;background-image: url(Images/i24x24_info.png);' class='iconDiv'></div>";
```

Comment: Is there any system in your use of `'` and `"` or is it completely random?

Comment: i guess it's a matter of missing or having extra single or double quotes.

Comment: @Uriel_SVK The OP uses double quotes in the programming language used to create the HTML and single quotes inside the HTML itself.

Comment: @MrLister  How do you explain `<img id="+"Img"+ this.panelId+"  src="+"Images/i24_grey-info.png"+" />` then?

Comment: @Uriel_SVK You start halfway through the first literal there and end in the middle of the last literal. So the first quote you mention is the end quote of the first literal.

Comment: @MrLister Nope, with his logic it should be `<img id='"+"Img"+ this.panelId+"' src='"+"Images/i24_grey-info.png"+"' />`. And also before edits there was this `style='width:34px;align:center; background-image='Images/i24_grey-info.png'`, but he repaired that since then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is incorrect. There is no `align` style, use `text-align`. Use a colon after `background-image`, and `url()` around the image URL:

```
style='width:34px; text-align:center; background-image:url(Images/i24_grey-info.png)'
```

You might also have to set the height of the `div` to the height of the image.

Comment: @user930514: If the element is larger than the background image it will repeat by default, you can use `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to stop it from repeating.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
background-image:Images/i24_grey-info.png;
```

by

```
background:url('Images/i24_grey-info.png') no-repeat;
```

I have had similar situations before. Try to use shorthand codes as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

in the first line you are passing grey-info.png to img tag however in the second line you are passing it to background-img

Answer (score -1):

Se the height also for the div when using background-image:

```
<div id='" + this.panelId + "Icon-1" + "'  style='width:34px;height:34px;align:center; background-image='Images/i24_grey-info.png' class='iconDiv'></div>"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your css syntax is wrong. Should be:

```
style='width:34px; align:center; background-image: (Images/i24_grey-info.png)'
```

The other problem is connected with div height, which is set to 0 on default when there is no content in it. You have to set the height to see the image then:

```
style='width:34px; height: 50px; align:center; background-image: (Images/i24_grey-info.png)'
```